# Как выровнять на 4 длину массива?

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм для выравнивания длины массива на 4.

Например, у меня есть массив из 7 байт. Следовательно, мне нужно дополнить этот массив еще одним нулевым байтом, чтобы длина стала равна 8.

Сам никак не соображу как это рассчитать.

Comment: что значит _есть массив из 7 байт. Следовательно, мне нужно дополнить этот массив еще одним нулевым байтом_?

Comment: @badc0de32 Чёт я не совсем понял что требуется. Необходимо что-бы длинна массива всегда была кратна 4м?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно над длиной произвести следующие битовые операции

```
(Length + 3) & !3
```

И вообще для выравнивания по границе `m` используется следующая формула

```
(Length + (m - 1)) & !(m - 1)
```

Comment: @Grundy как они поняли друг-друга?

Comment: @V.Dmitriy элементарно. "Выравнивание на 2^n" - типовая задача и кроме ее формулировки говорить больше нечего.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в каких случаях применяется такое выравнивание?

Comment: @V.Dmitriy загрузчик MZPE-файлов (то есть практически всех исполняемых в винде) постоянно подобные штуки делает. Только там все сложнее в итоге.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy работа со страничной памятью, работа с битмапами...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, спасибо большое!  Могли бы вы объяснить, пожалуйста, смысл этих битовых операций? Я, кстати, видел такой прием в отладчике, но сакральный смысл не уловил.